# Find $\int_{|z+2|=1}\frac{e^{z^2}}{z^{1995}}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Find $\int_{|z+2|=1}\frac{e^{z^2}}{z^{1995}}dz$, where $z\in \mathbb{C}$.

My current struggle with this problem is first just parametrizing $\{z:|z+2|=1\}$.

How can I find a $\gamma:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ that would give me this curve?

Thanks in advance

Comment: One parameterization of $|z| = 1$ is $z = e^{it}$, so by translation one parameterization of $|z+2|=1$ is $z=-2+e^{it}$. That's not really necessary, though. Look closely at the location of the pole of the integrand compared to the circle.

Comment: Isn't the easiest way to show that $z \mapsto \frac{e^{z^2}}{z^{1995}}$ is meromorphic on the disc with center of affix $2$ and radius $1$?

Comment: @OlivierRoche: Why do you write "meromorphic"?

Comment: @ChristianBTo be honest it's because I'm not an analyst at all. Thus, I had to dig deep into my memory and I wrote meromorphic just to be safe, analytic was good. ;)

Answer (score 4):

The function $f(z) = \frac{e^{z^{2}}}{z^{1995}}$ is analytic in the region $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z+2|<1+\epsilon\}$ since its only pole is at $z=0.$ Therefore by Cauchy's theorem,

$$\int_{|z+2|=1}\frac{e^{z^2}}{z^{1995}}dz = 0.$$